# Stop left slide menu from pushing content with css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, elementor

I deal with the following problem.

I have a wordpress theme in which there is a left side menu that when I press the hamburger button, it pushes the whole content, header and main container to the left.

What should I look into?

I have tried changing position from fixed to absolute and overflow to overlay but I might now doing it correct.

I cannot provide code because I don't know which file is responsible so, any chance where should I look into?

I am talking about Atelier theme.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat depends on how the menu is implemented, and without further details it's somewhat hard to say 100% what will work for you.

That said though, if you want to display your side menu over top of the content without pushing it to the right then you would want to set the `Z-Index` of the menu such that it renders above the rest of the content on the page.

Here is some details that might help you achieve what you are looking to do:
[Z-Index](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Comment: I know that you want more details but the implementation was too complicated. However, thanks for your answer but unfortunately, the z-index didn't work as well.

Comment: Is this a themeforest theme? or something we could look at a demo online? that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes it is a themeforest theme. The demo I am talking about is this: https://www.portotheme.com/wordpress/porto/shop10/

I left the idea of atelier theme

I want to add a header with a hamburger icon at top left that will toggle the menu like g-star's website.

Comment: So checked out your theme. If I understand your description of what your looking to achieve, it is somewhat like your theme does when the screen size is less than 976px. So you could modify the style such that this is the normal behaviour on larger breakpoints. However, the theme pushes the content at that breakpoint by setting the right position to a -260px, checkout the class .panel-open .page-wrapper 

Removing the negative right position should allow the theme to work like the g-star website.

Comment: I could not understand completely what you proposed. 
I have managed to create a header bar with an hamburger that with javascript opens my sidebar. 
But the sidebar pushes the content to the left and it is not remaining responsive.

Comment: The sidebar I use is this: https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Setting the position attribute for the Manu should do the trick. More information: [CSS position property](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with the position attribute. I may drop the theme choice and go to another one.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on hamburger. please check body or content added margin for left side. if left side content margin added then remove margin-left: 0px !important. If added new class then help with jQuery remove this class when your click on hamburger.

Comment: That's a good approach I might try. I would like to avoid any javascript but I may give this a try. Thanks!